# Unable to record an Android app using JMeter

Tags: android, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, blazemeter

I'm trying to record browser activities of my Android mobile in Jmeter as explained [here](http://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy). I'm done with all the above settings, but Jmeter is unable to record the traffic.

Is it like, mobile and laptop should be connected to same internet source (wi-fi) or is it like laptop should be made as a hotspot and the we need to connect mobile to the hotspot?

Also, please let me know if anyone has done any other settings than the one mentioned above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Mobile device and laptop need to be on the same network in order to have the mobile device use the laptop as an HTTP proxy. You should also turn off cell data (plane mode on an iPhone) to make sure you're not trying to connect via the cell data.

Comment: Thanks @Ophir. It worked like magic but there is one issue that I am facing. When I change the proxy of my Android device to that of my laptop, it works fine for the browser and the requests are recorded. But, the apps are unable to access the internet. My requirement is record the requests coming from apps. Kindly suggest a probabale solution.

Comment: I have neither Android nor iPhone, but I guess, that you should configure your app for using laptop as HTTP proxy. But I can be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the native android applications fail to connect once the proxy is set , Same goes for few sites as well, The solution is to either manually add API's to the jmetre and test or most probably the connections setting in the application configs needs to be changed in order for jmetre to record the script , This basically seems to be SSL issue and is to secure the apps from accessing data on proxy.For more detail blaze metre documentation shall help

https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Recording-Using-Android-Devices-Recording-Using-Android-Devices